# Grep exit status not returning expected value

Tags: grep

In file "WAP" word is there. When I am running  grep command `grep -i "WAP" filename`. I am getting exit status 0. That is fine.

But when I am searching for those words which they are not in file. I am still getting exit status zero.

Comment: can you provide some example?

Comment: File has data WAP,

Comment: it works for me:
    `jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ cat filename`
    WAP,
    `jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ cat filename2`
    nop
    `jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ grep -i "WAP" filename; echo $?`
    WAP,
    0
    `jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ grep -i "WAP" filename2; echo $?`
    1
(sorry for formating, but comments do not have such a great possibilities)

Comment: @HarkiratSingh: It *might* help if you would (1) run commands that illustrate your problem (similar to the ones Jakuje showed, above), (2) [edit] your question, (3) copy and paste the screen output from step 1 from your terminal into your question, (4) select the screen output text and type (Ctrl+K) to format it (and (5) save your edits).